# Invalid values in Switch-Case without default label

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I'm a big fan of skipping the "default:" label in a enum-switch-case. So I get compiler warnings, when the enum has a new value which is not handled by the switch-case.

Now a colleague stated, that when passing an integer to this switch-case which is not covered by the enumeration I will get a segmentation fault.

At least the gcc we re using handles it correctly. Also the [Visual Studio documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0t5wee3.aspx) says: If "none of the constants match the constants in the case labels and default label is not present >>> Control is transferred to the statement after the switch statement."

Is this the standard and thus the behaviour of all (or at least the most) compilers?

Comment: Maybe your colleague is thinking of the code after the case table. If it uses incorrectly configured resources, which the table would otherwise have configured, then, yes, not having a default could cause a segfault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MS compiler seems to do it right. Here's what the standard says (6.4.2/5):

> If no case constant matches the condition, and if there is a `default` label, control
>   passes to the statement labeled by the `default` label. If no case matches and if there is no `default` then none of the statements in the switch is executed.

Answer (score 1):

It can cause a segmentation fault only if skipped case breaks your code. Otherwise no compiler should emit code that will generate a segmentation fault.

Example that will generate a fault:

```
 switch(flag) {
     case Type1: p = malloc(200); break;
     case Type2: p = malloc(100); break;
 }
 memcpy(p, source, 10);
```

Comment: @KarthikT: I don't think there's any "legal way to segfault the code", because there is no notion of segfault in the language. Segfaults are the result of doing something *illegal*.

Comment: ok, let me elabourate. +1 for an example of a legal/standards complying situation which might in the near future lead to a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

[stmt.switch] states:

> If no case matches and if there is no default then none of the
>   statements in the switch is executed.

So yes, VS follows the standard in this regard.